# If cell in range is not empty insert new row below

Tags: excel, vba

I have numbers and letters in range B2:B60.

I would like, if there is a data in cells B2:B60, to insert one row below.

So it would look like:

```
   A B
1    e -> EntireRow.Insert below
2    
3    3 -> EntireRow.Insert below
4    a -> EntireRow.Insert below
5    
6    er -> EntireRow.Insert below
7    
8    w -> EntireRow.Insert below
```

I have tried:

```
Dim Rng As Range
For Each Rng In Range("B2:B60")
    If Is Not Empty (Rng.Value) Then
        Rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## If Not IsEmpty

```
Option Explicit

Sub EmptyRows()

    Dim Rng As Range

    For Each Rng In Range("B2:B60")
        If Not IsEmpty(Rng) Then
            Rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You *might* need to reverse your loop to prevent your data moving out of the input range during execution when you insert new rows. Not sure how `For Each` loops handle things like that.

```
Sub Main()

Dim R As Range
Set R = Range("Sheet1!C4:C20")
Dim FR As Integer
Dim LR As Integer

FR = 1 ' First Row in R
LR = R.Rows.Count ' Last Row in R

Dim Index As Integer

For Index = LR To FR Step -1
    If Not IsEmpty(R(Index)) Then
        R(Index).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next

End Sub
```